# In AngularJS, why isn't a $scope variable accessible from a simple function?

Tags: angularjs

My code is as shown below:

```
angular.module('xyz', [])
    .controller('listController', ['$scope', 
        function($scope) {
            $scope.deliveryOptions = 0;
            var vm = this;

            function doTransaction() {
                console.log('delivery options is ' + vm.$scope.deliveryOptions);
            }
        }
    ]);
```

Here inside `console.log(delivery options)`, it gives me error that `it is Unable to get property 'deliveryOptions' of undefined or null reference`. So how can I access that variable?

Comment: I prefer @Marcus answer, but you could also pass `$scope.deliveryOptions` as a parameter to `doTransaction()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the $scope is not defined on the vm object.
To solve this you should either define everything on the $scope object like this

```
angular.module('xyz', [])
    .controller('listController', ['$scope', 
        function($scope) {
            $scope.deliveryOptions = 0;

            $scope.doTransaction = function() {
                console.log('delivery options is ' + $scope.deliveryOptions);
            }
        }
    ]);
```

Or on the vm object

```
angular.module('xyz', [])
    .controller('listController', 
        function() {
            var vm = this;
            vm.deliveryOptions = 0;

            vm.doTransaction = function() {
                console.log('delivery options is ' + vm.deliveryOptions);
            }
        }
    );
```

Mixing vm and $scope is not the best way to go

Answer (score 2):

**Use either `$scope` or `controller as`, not both**

The primary issue is you're mixing original AngularJS 1.x `$scope` usage, with the `controller as` design pattern that uses `vm` (meaning "view model"), which started with Angular 1.5.

You need to pick one or the other, and then your code will work just fine.

If you go with the cleaner and less error-prone `vm` and `controller as` design pattern, you simply use `vm` rather than $scope:

```
angular.module('xyz', [])
    .controller('listController', function() {
        var vm = this
        vm.deliveryOptions = 0
        vm.doTransaction = function() {
            console.log('delivery options is ' + vm.deliveryOptions)
        }
     })
```

And then in your view, you use `vm.doTransaction()` to call your function and display your variable.